# Water shuts off and faucets spit air. Well system

Tags: well

Recently my water has been cutting off for 10 or so seconds while taking a shower. Now Everytime I turn the water on the faucets sputter like they are releasing air. This happens everywhere in the house and not just one bathroom.

Comment: Well too low? Or have you taken too much too quickly?

Comment: First thought would be to check that the well is functioning properly and that there are no leaks.

Comment: Plumbing systems are usually closed systems.  The only way to usually get air into them is to remove a part, drain a tank, or suck air from the intake(well).  I would suspect the well is too low also.  Has any work been done to the plumbing?

Comment: There is a problem with the mechanisms that try to maintain the proper amount of air in the pressure tank.  There are several different schemes for this, so it's hard to guess what your problem is without more info.  It's probably best to get a well system plumber to look at it.

Comment: @HotLicks the snifter valve and tank without a bladder or diaphragm is a formerly common but **highly unusual at this point in time** setup.

Comment: @Alex is your pump aboveground, or a submersible pump in the well? Any leak on the suction side of an aboveground pump will pull in air. A submersible pump only sucks air when the water level is too low in the well, since the whole pipe up the well is under pressure.